# Giving Union of types as `bound` argument of TypeVar and calling overloaded function that requires one of the types, type checker reports an error

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

Checking the following code with mypy, it says `30: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "T"; expected "X"`.

But there are decorated declarations of `f` so we should be able to pass value of class `X` or `Y` as the argument `a`.

**Question 1:**
Could not we use @overload and TypeVar(bound=Union) at the same time ? Or I misunderstand something ?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union, overload


class X:
    pass


class Y:
    pass


@overload
def f(a: X):
    ...


@overload
def f(a: Y):
    ...


def f(a):
    return


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[X, Y])


def func(a: T) -> T:
    f(a)
    return a
```

I tried another example as following and it does not make type errors.

**Question 2**: What makes the difference between overloaded function and classes having same method ?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union


class X:
    def method(self) -> float:
        return 1.0


class Y:
    def method(self) -> float:
        return 1.0


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[X, Y])


def func(a: T) -> T:
    a.method()
    return a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1**: Could not we use @overload and TypeVar(bound=Union) at the same time ? Or I misunderstand something ?

The problem is with `TypeVar`: what you want is `T = TypeVar("T", X, Y)` because both `X` and `Y` should be accepted. See the *usage* paragraph in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). The `bound` parameter is used only if you want to define an **upper** bound to the types, basically you are specifying the constraining superclass. For more details, see [Type variables with an upper bound](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound).

> **Question 2**: What makes the difference between overloaded function and classes having same method ?

The `@overload` decorator is useful in case there are two functions/methods sharing the **same scope**, in fact

> The variants and the implementations must be adjacent in the code: think of them as one indivisible unit.

<sub>[Source](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#runtime-behavior)</sub>